# Creating CountDown in CakePHP 2.0

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to create a countdown kinda thing in my app, the column '`end_date`' is in DATETIME format. if i use:

`echo $thing['table_name']['end_date']`

output is(todays' date):

```
2012-08-16
```

where as i want the output to be:

```
3 days left
```

now how can i do this? i'll be using this in a lot of different views, i found this [tutorial](http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/9471.aspx) but i'd have to put this code again and again. i wanna solve this with a more OOP approach. Is it possible to put this in the Model directly or something of that sort?

Any direction would be of great help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use virtualFields in this case

```
class Thing {
    var $virtualFields = array( 
    'timeleft' => "IF(Thing.end_date IS NOT NULL AND Thing.end_date <> '0000-00-00',CONCAT(DATEDIFF(Thing.end_date,CURDATE()),' days left'),'-')"
    ); 
}
```

now you will get this field under `echo $thing['table_name']['timeleft']`

Comment: wow! you have no idea what this solution has made me feel, thanks. one more thing though, How do i put checks for "0 days" and "1 day"(grammar).

Comment: IF(Thing.end_date IS NOT NULL AND Thing.end_date <> '0000-00-00',IF(CONCAT(DATEDIFF(Thing.end_date,CURDATE()),IF(DATEDIFF(Thing.end_date,CURDATE()=1,' day left',' days left')),'-')
let me know if any error is there, I have updated this directly :)

Comment: `Database Error


Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'`

Comment: IF(
  Thing.end_date IS NOT NULL AND Thing.end_date <> '0000-00-00',
  CONCAT(DATEDIFF(Thing.end_date,CURDATE()),
     IF(DATEDIFF(Thing.end_‌​date,CURDATE())=1,' day left',' days left')
  ),
  '-'
)